# Graphene-django returns null node instead of just node field

Tags: python, django, django-models, graphene-python

I am facing a strange problem with graphene and Django. The documentation seems to lack a solution and I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**I have the following models:**

```
Class Sentence(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    body = models.TextField(default=None)

Class Summary(models.Model):
    sentence = models.ForeignKey(Sentence, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(default=None)
```

(Each sentence can have multiple summaries)

**And the following schema:**

```
Class SentenceType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Sentence
        filter_fields = {"ref": ["exact"]}
        interfaces = (graphene.Node, )

Class SummaryType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Summary
        filter_field = {"text": ["icontains"]}
        interfaces = (graphene.Node, )

Class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_sentences = DjangoFilterConnectionField(SentenceType)
    sentence = graphene.Field(SentenceType, ref=graphene.string(), body=graphene.string())
    all_summary = all_provvedimenti = DjangoFilterConnectionField(SummaryType)
    summary = graphene.field(SummaryType, id=graphene.Int(), text=graphene.string())

def resolve_all_summaries(self, context, **kwargs):
    return models.Summary.objects.all()
```

It can occur that there is one or more summaries in my database with no corresponding sentence.

**Now, when I query**

```
{
  allSummaries{
    edges{
      node{
        text
        sentence{
          ref
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the the sentence exists for the summary, no problem at all. 
**But if there is no corresponding sentence I get:**

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Sentence matching query does not exist.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 9
        }
      ]
    }
],
...,
...,
"data":[
    ...,
    {
      "node": null
    },
    {
      "node":{
        "text": "blah blah blah sentence summary"
        "sentence": {
          "ref": "sentence_reference"
        }
      }
    }
    {
      "node": null
    },
    ...,
]
```

Naturally, the output I would expect is that whenever a corresponding sentence does not exist for a summary node it would still give me back the text of the summary and "sentence": null or [].

I had no luck in the documentation or google. Seems I am the only one having this issue. I can't understand whether I am making some mistake in Django, graphene or it is just a bug.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried a try except around your resolve code? It looks like you're getting an exception out of that code. Also, your Sentence is inheriting from models.model instead of models.Model, not sure if intentional or not.

Comment: I know I could handle the exception, but it wouldn't solve my problem, being the error at the last line of the code: it needs to return a dataset which is handled by graphene; If I handle manually the exception I should also manually filter the dataset twice (summaries with and without sentence containing a certain word) and then combine them, which I'd like to avoid. models.Model is just a typo I made here... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change the `all_summary` variable in this line

```
all_summary = all_provvedimenti = DjangoFilterConnectionField(SummaryType)
```

to `allSummaries`

and then change your function name in

```
def resolve_all_summaries(self, context, **kwargs):
```

to `resolve_allSummaries` as well

then you can query with:

```
 {
  allSummaries{
    edges{
      node{
        text
        sentence{
          ref
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

all three of those identifiers refer to the same thing and therefor need to match